# Need to write unit test cases for redux reducers which are using combine reducers

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I want to write some unit test cases which are using `combnereducers()` function. I have something like following.

`myReducers1.js`

```
function reducer1(state = {}, action) {
   //some logic
}

function reducer2(state = {value1: {}}, action) {
  //some logic
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({reducer1, reducer2})

export default appRecuer;
```

So is there any way to test the code written inside the `reducer1` and `reducer2`? If there is then how can i reach to the `reducer1` and `reducer2` function which are inside `myReducers1.js`.
I have already gone through to the [Testing Redux combined reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800467/testing-redux-combined-reducers) but this is having the different context. So please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: export reducer1 and reducer2 and test them indivudually (you dont need to test 'combineReducers' it is supposed to be tested by redux ;) )

Comment: Are you talking about testing individual reducers? If so then just import reducer in your test file and pass mock objects to it.

Comment: All of my reducers are in a single file. And i am combining them by using combineReducers() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jest:

mock a prevState:

```
const state = {var1: value};
```

make sure both reducer and action are declared or imported in the test file and run your test:

```
test('reducer test', () => {
  expect(reducer(state, action).toBe(your result);
});
```

exemple:

```
const testAction = { type:'INCREMENT_AGE' };

const prevState = { age: 37, name: "John Doe"};

const reducer = (state, action) => (action.type === "INCREMENT_AGE" ?{...state, age: state.age + 1} : state)

test('reducer test', () => {
  expect(reducer(prevState, testAction).toEqual({name: "John Doe", age: 38});
});
```

Comment: All of my reducers are in a single file. And i am combining them by using combineReducers() function. I got the solution from your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect answer <3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have exported individual reducer and action, you just call reducer with custom/desired action and pass initial state or desired state and test for changed state object.

```
import reducer from '../src/reducers/reducer1';
import * as actions from '../src/actions/action1';

describe('reducer1', () => {
  it('should return the initial state', () => {
    const state = reducer(undefined, {});
    expect(state.loading).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('should handle CUSTOM_ACTION', () => {
    const action = {
      type: actions.CUSTOM_ACTION
    };
    const state = reducer({}, action);

    expect(state.foo).toEqual('desired value');
  });
});
```

Comment: All of my reducers are in a single file. And i am combining them by using combineReducers() function. I got the solution from above answer. Thanks for your help.